# Uploading data to Google Cloud Storage using the Google API returns "Bad Request: key invalid"

Tags: ios, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the Google Cloud Storage API for obj-c for inserting data into a bucket, but I get a 400 server error back:

{reason:"keyInvalid" message:"Bad Request" domain:"usageLimits"}

I'm using the Service Account Authentication method by setting the APIKey property of GTLServiceStorage as the generated key value from the developer console and as I understand I do not need the access token as for the OAuth2 authentication?

I have tried several combinations for the various fields with no luck. The code can be seen below:

```
_serviceStorage = [GTLServiceStorage new];
_serviceStorage.additionalHTTPHeaders = @{@"x-goog-project-id": LTProjectID};
    _serviceStorage.APIKey = ServiceAccountAPIKeyFromJsonKey;

GTLUploadParameters *uploadParam 
  = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:@"audio/mp4"];

GTLStorageObject *storageObj = [GTLStorageObject object];
storageObj.name = @"file_name"

GTLStorageObjectAccessControl *objAccessControl 
  = [GTLStorageObjectAccessControl new];

objAccessControl.entity = @"allUsers";
objAccessControl.email = @"5942472xxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
objAccessControl.role = @"OWNER";

storageObj.acl = @[objAccessControl];

GTLQueryStorage *query 
  = [GTLQueryStorage queryForObjectsInsertWithObject:storageObj 
                                              bucket:@"my_bucket"                 
                                    uploadParameters:uploadParam];

GTLServiceTicket *ticket 
   = [_serviceStorage executeQuery:query 
                 completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, 
                                     id object, 
                                     NSError *error) {        
  // error: {reason:"keyInvalid" message:"Bad Request" domain:"usageLimits"}
  }
}];

ticket.uploadProgressBlock ...
```

Comment: Reading the docs, an access token is still needed for authentication: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests. However, I can't figure out how to use the obj-c Google API for doing something similar. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I made another solution, where I upload it to my web service on Google Compute and from there add it to the bucket.